# JAR export - Duplicate entry org/apache/log4j warning

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j, executable-jar

When I export JAR file in Eclipse, I've got this warning:
[image: this warning]

I has zero impact to functionality. However, I can't figure out the cause.

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
                <artifactId>swingx-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.5-1</version>
            </dependency>       
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You should remove `log4j`, since `apache-log4j-extras` already contains all the classes from `log4j`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz where to remove what exactly?

Comment: Looking further into the two jars (making a diff of them), you should keep both of them: each one contains classes that are not present in the other one. Unfortunately they also have a big common part, so you'll alway have the _"Duplicate entry"_ warning.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong in my project? It's bcs the jars contents?

Comment: Can you explain why you have added `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` this in your pom file? Why not following conventions? locate your production code into `src/main/java/<packageName>` and your unit tests into `src/test/java/<packageName>`... remove also the exclude for `*.java` in your resources configuration...

Comment: @pburgr: yes, the duplicate entries are normal in this situation.